# replacing a variable of a multidimensional session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional session array that is set. Session start is called at the top of the file and all the fields are set as the examples

```
//set variables 
$locked="unlocked";$name="BMX";$sport_activity="sport";$quantity="1";$price="600";

//set variables to array 
$sports_array = array(0 => array(
'i_locked' => $locked,
'i_name' => $name,
'i_quantity' => $quantity,
'i_price' => $price, 
'i_sport_activity' => $sport_activity,
'i_base_price' => $price));

 //set multidimensional session array 
$_SESSION["activity"][] = $sports_array;
```

Then the array is called in a PHP loop.

```
$arrayID = -1; 
//foreach loop  
foreach($_SESSION['activity'] as $key){ 
  foreach($key as $list){   
  $arrayID += 1;        
  ?>
  //echo all the array items individually in separate divs 
  <form>
    <div>
      <?php echo $list['i_locked']?>
    </div>
    // ..... etc
    <input type="hidden" name="ArrayNum" value="<?=$arrayID?>">
    <input type='submit' name='Confirm_button'>
  </form>
```

All of this works, what i would like to then do is change a variable and add new ones.

I have come across array_push() for adding new fields onto an array. And i have tried the following below, but either it adds an entire array stack or delete's the array stack.

```
if(isset($_POST["Confirm_button"])){
   $time = 'pm';
   $date = 'feb';
   $_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']]['i_locked'] = 'locked';
   array_push($_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']],'i_time'=>$time,'i_date'=>$date);
}
```

Any help or a point in the right direction for best practices would be most appreciated

************************* Re- Edit ****************************************

Credit to @Suchit Kumar 
Was able to get the problem fixed based on his help.

The first issue of changing an element of the array works with the following code. And correctly finds the element that needs changing.

```
 $_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']][0]['i_locked'] = 'locked';
```

The second issue of adding new elements to the array works with the following code.

```
 $time = 'pm';
 $date = 'feb';
 $_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']][0]['i_time'] = $time; 
 $_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']][0]['i_time'] = $date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I think you can not use key value pair in array_push without using array('key'=>'value') format.` in this case you have to do something like this dynamically:

and the way you are creating  `$_SESSION["activity"][]=$sports_array;`.your array will come on index `['activity'][0][0]`.

IT is an Example to point out the problem But you need to follow this Dynamically by creating dynamic indexes.

```
<?php 
 $time = 'pm';
 $date = 'feb';
$_SESSION['activity'][0][0]['i_time']=$time;// when already some elements are there with the key
$_SESSION['activity'][0][0]['i_date']=$date;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<pre>";
```

if you want to add another array do $_SESSION['activity']:

```
       $time1 = 'am';
       $date1 = 'mar';
array_push($_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']],array('i_new'=>$time1,'i_new1'=>$date1));//createing new key and pussing the array.
```

to update any value in an array do this:

check if:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['activity'][0][1]['i_time'])){// you can use foreach to access eack key value pair before if condition
   $_SESSION['activity'][0][1]['i_time']=$newtime;

}
    ?>
```

**NOTE:** this is only to show your how you will do in your original code.

Comment: Hey Suchit, Thanks for the input. 
Works great when there is only 1 element in the array, but adding another array element only effects the first part of the array. rather than the corresponding array part.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting you.Please elaborate.

Comment: So the first array element effected correctly adds the date and time, as per your code 

The second array element only effects the first elements additional  date and time 

1 item in the array and additional elements added in date we put date1 and in time we put time1 as examples then this is what prints out
 
array[0] = (i_locked = hi, i_sport='more', i_date='date1',i_time='time1');

however when 2 elements are in the array and we set the 2nd set to date2 and time2 

array[0] = (i_locked = hi, i_sport='more', i_date='date2',i_time='time2');
array[1] = (i_locked = hi, i_sport='more');

Comment: i'll post the output then point out what you want as per your requirement.

Comment: In repsonce to your output, Yep ive got that and it works, but it doesn't for any additional array elements added to the stack. i.e when we go to array [1]. Any additional adds only effect the first element array[0]

Comment: then you have to use the index 1 to access it like:['activity'][0][1]

Comment: As i thought, this was my original problem, how do i assign the correct index to the correct array selected?

Comment: just create a dummy structure and post me what you want to achieve dynamically not by fixed indexes.

Comment: The structure was in the original post. Basically a user adds an item to the array, these items are posted with pre-set variables that require editing by the user. There will be more than 1 array item added at a time. Then a user is required to confirm each array edits separately. This is done using a form button, that then selects the  index array dynamicaly and adds two varaibles i_time and i_date to it.

Comment: ie 

  $_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']]['someVar'] = $addedVar;

Comment: see last line in edited answer it will dynamically create your index and push the array data.

Comment: yea again this was my original problem, whats happening is it's overwriting a pre-existing array element, by deleting its pre-existing values. With the array_push function it disregards all the previously created values and only adds in the date and time variables. 

What needs to happen is array [0] has to add two variables onto the end of it and then edit 1 of it's pre-existing variable. Ill add output to the end of the code as an edit

Comment: it will overwrite if the index already exists so first check if(isset($_SESSION['activity'][$_POST['ArrayNum']])).then follow  $_SESSION['activity'][0][0]['i_date']=$date; format else assign the array.i'll update based on condition.

Comment: Hey Suchit, Thank you for all your help on this much appreciated. Unfortunately this only works for a limited number of array elements. The code needs to be applied to 100's of array elements. It's not feasibly to code in if isset statements for 100 array elements. I will try work some more on a recursive answer and get back to you. Thank you again.